# How to select elements property in an array? python

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have a lot of similar arrays, **i need to select properties of 'geo_lon' and 'geo_lat'**. This one is just for an example:

```
[{'value': '658747', 'unrestricted_value': 'Алтайский край, Крутихинский р-н, с Волчно-Бурлинское, ул Партизанская, д 98', 'data': {'postal_code': '658747', 'is_closed': False, 'type_code': 'СОПС', 'address_str': 'Алтайский край, Крутихинский р-н, с Волчно-Бурлинское, ул Партизанская, д 98', 'address_kladr_id': '2202300000600', 'address_qc': '0', 'geo_lat': 54.053755, 'geo_lon': 80.768417, 'schedule_mon': '09:00-17:00, обед 13:00-14:00', 'schedule_tue': None, 'schedule_wed': '09:00-17:00, обед 13:00-14:00', 'schedule_thu': '09:00-17:00, обед 13:00-14:00', 'schedule_fri': '09:00-17:00, обед 13:00-14:00', 'schedule_sat': '09:00-16:00, обед 13:00-14:00', 'schedule_sun': None}}]
```

Im trying to do this (list_1 is an array, which i ve shown, im getting as a response)

```
for index, element in enumerate(list_1):
    d = dadata.suggest("postal_unit", element)
    
    for feature in d['data']:
        coor = feature['geo_lon']
        print(coor)
```

But this gives me an error:

```
for feature in d['data']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Im new to python

Comment: From the error at the end, it seems like d is a list, therefore requiring an integer to specify an index. E.g. d[0]

Comment: Yeah. It seems like a list. So then how to select elements properties ('geo_lon' and 'geo_lat') in this list?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the following code.

```
for index, element in enumerate(list_1):
    data = element["data"]
    geo_lat = data["geo_lat"]
    geo_lon = data["geo_lon"]
    print("geo_lat: " + str(geo_lat) )
    print("geo_lon: " + str(geo_lon) )
```

Comment: If this solves your problem, you can remove the enumeration as it is redundant

Comment: getting an error: data = element["data"]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Maybe there s a way to convert list into json. So, after doing it, it'd be easier to me to work with.  Ive used json.dumps, but it didnt work to me too

Comment: what does `data` look like?

Comment: 'data': {'postal_code': '658747', 'is_closed': False, 'type_code': 'СОПС', 'address_str': 'Алтайский край, Крутихинский р-н, с Волчно-Бурлинское, ул Партизанская, д 98', 'address_kladr_id': '2202300000600', 'address_qc': '0', 'geo_lat': 54.053755, 'geo_lon': 80.768417, 'schedule_mon': '09:00-17:00, обед 13:00-14:00', 'schedule_tue': None, 'schedule_wed': '09:00-17:00, обед 13:00-14:00', 'schedule_thu': '09:00-17:00, обед 13:00-14:00', 'schedule_fri': '09:00-17:00, обед 13:00-14:00', 'schedule_sat': '09:00-16:00, обед 13:00-14:00', 'schedule_sun': None}

Comment: so i need from data only properties of geo_lon and geo_lat

Comment: It appear `d` is a list, probably there are square braces wrapping data. Something like ['data': {...}]